# DuplicateKeyException: Bulk write operation error on server:

Tags: spring, mongodb

I am new in MongoDB and trying to execute a very simple query to save collection to the database, but receive the error `Bulk write operation error on server`.

Entity:

```java
@Document("role")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "id") <--------- compare only by unique field `name`
public class Role {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @NotBlank
    @NonNull
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private ERole name;
}
```

- ERole:

```java
public enum ERole {ROLE_USER, ROLE_MODERATOR, ROLE_ADMIN}
```

- logic:

```java
        Collection<Role> rolesFromDb = repository.findAll();  < --------- (1)
        Collection<Role> rolesFromEnumSet = Arrays.stream(ERole.values()).map(Role::new).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        if (!(rolesFromDb.containsAll(rolesFromEnumSet) &&
             rolesFromEnumSet.containsAll(rolesFromDb))
        ) {
            rolesFromEnumSet.removeAll(rolesFromDb); < ------------------ (2)
            repository.saveAll(rolesFromEnumSet); < --------------------- (3)
        }
```

I have a single record in the database and receive the next collection in `rolesFromDatabase` variable (line (1):

> Role(id=63dc16b253565a43cee65848, name=ROLE_USER)

In line (2) a `rolesFromEnuSet` has an expected set:

> 0 = {Role@9387} "Role(id=null, name=ROLE_ADMIN)"
>
> 1 = {Role@9388} "Role(id=null, name=ROLE_MODERATOR)"

So, the database doesn't contain remembered records.

Why do I receive a "Duplicate error" in line (3)?

Answer (score 0):

Your `EqualsAndHashCode` is comparing by ID, not name. This means that the `rolesFromEnumSet.removeAll(rolesFromDb))` code is not removing anything in `rolesFromEnumSet`

This means that inside your transaction, you are actually left with 4 records:

```
Role(id=63dc16b253565a43cee65848, name=ROLE_USER)
Role(id=null, name=ROLE_USER)
Role(id=null, name=ROLE_MODERATOR)
Role(id=null, name=ROLE_ADMIN)
```

You'll receive a duplicate key error because it tries to save an additional role with the name `ROLE_USER`